# Firebase 3 - Ionic 2 - .on('value' , snapshot => { this...} this is null

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

When I try to retrieve data using Firebase 3 SDK for Web, "this" is showing as null. Any idea why this might occur ?

```
this.mainApp = firebase.initializeApp(config);
FBGet(path){
    return this.mainApp.database().ref(path);
}
...
GetUser(){
    this.appData.FBGet('users/'+user.uid).on('value', function(snapshot) {
        var objUser = snapshot.val();
        //the following statement is throwing an exception cause 'this' is null
        this.events.publish('user:update', objUser);
    });
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using an arrow function for `FBGet`, so `this` will not be bound to your component/provider.

```
GetUser(){
  this.appData.FBGet('users/'+user.uid).on('value', (snapshot) => {
    const objUser = snapshot.val();
    // this is now bound to the component using the fat arrow =>
    this.events.publish('user:update', objUser);
  });
}
```

The above solution will only work *if* `this.events` is a property on the same component/provider.